# Multiple conditionals with the same body

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I do multiple checks in my Python code with the same body to avoid violate DRY?

**For example I need to check this in my Django project:**

```
if not obj.name == instance.name:
   post_response('CHANGED')
if not obj.address == instance.address:
   post_response('CHANGED')
if not obj.phone_number == instance.phone_number:
   post_response('CHANGED')
if not obj.postal_code == instance.postal_code:
   post_response('CHANGED')
```

I have multiple more conditionals left to do. It just feels redundant because the body is the same in every conditional operation.

Comment: A list and a loop would perfectly do the job

Comment: if it fails the first check i.e. if `obj.name` is *not equal* to `instance.name` then you do not need the rest of the conditions since the post call is the same in all of them just check for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your checking the same attribute on both objects you could compare them dynamically like this:

```
attributes = ['name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'postal_code']

for attribute in attributes:
    if not getattr(obj, attribute) == getattr(instance, attribute):
        post_response('CHANGED')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a built-in function in Python called `getattr()`, from Python Doc:

> [getattr Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

Which accepts 2 parameters, one is the object to get the attribute, and the other is the attribute name, in a `str` type.

So, for the question, you can make a list/tuple with the names of the attribute that you want to check, and iterate over them in a for loop:

```
attrNames = ('name', 'address', 'phone_numbers', 'postal_code')


for name in attrName:
if not getattr(obj, name) == getattr(instance, name):
     post_response('CHANGED')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine tests with logical operations like `and` or `or`.

```
if not (
        obj.name == instance.name and 
        obj.address == instance.address and 
        obj.phone_number == instance.phone_number and 
        obj.postal_code == instance.postal_code):
   post_response('CHANGED')
```

But this will not be equivalent to your code, as you used multiple `if`s instead of `elif`s, so your construct could fire multiple times and this will only fire once. You could do that by counting the amount of differences and then do your action that amount of times if that is expected behaviour.

```
changes = sum([
    obj.name != instance.name,
    obj.address != instance.address, 
    obj.phone_number != instance.phone_number,
    obj.postal_code != instance.postal_code])
for _ in range(changes):
   post_response('CHANGED')
```

But then again, you might want to consider if that sacrifices too much readability as with this, as here you'd need to know that you can sum booleans together and that a `range(0)` equals no iteration while your approach can be understood directly.